# Spring and Angular JS. Cant add new object to HashMap

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am trying to make simple webshop application and I have trouble handling adding items to cart. I want to add the item using angular js. 
Everything seems to be ok, "addToCart" method succeeds with "Product has been successfully added to cart!" alert. But there is nothing in the cart.

There is also statement in the browser console:

> angular.min.js:96 GET
>   http://localhost:8080/rest/cart/F976565EA460D3FDB0125FA7FAF868E3 400
>   ()

where F976565EA460D3FDB0125FA7FAF868E3 is cartId

REST controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/cart")
public class CartRestController {

@Autowired
private CartService cartService;

@Autowired
private ProductService productService;


/**
 * POST - Creates new Cart object
 * GET - Sends new Cart object with id = cartId
 * PUT - Updates Cart object with id = cartId
 * DELETE - Delete Cart object with id  = cartId
 */

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Cart create(@RequestBody Cart cart){
    System.out.println("Kontroler create");
    return cartService.create(cart);}


@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId)
{

    System.out.println("Kontroler read");

    return cartService.read(cartId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void update(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId, @RequestBody Cart cart){
    System.out.println("Kontroler update");

    cartService.update(cart,cartId);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId){
    System.out.println("Kontroler delete");

    cartService.delete(cartId);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void addItem(@PathVariable Integer productId, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
    Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
    if(cart== null)
    {
        cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
    }
    Product product = productService.findById(productId);
    if(product == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    cart.addItemToCart(new Item(product));
    cartService.update(cart, sessionId);
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void removeItem(@PathVariable Integer productId, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("Kontroler remove item");

    String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
    Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
    if(cart== null)
    {
        cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
    }
    Product product = productService.findById(productId);
    if(product == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    cart.removeItem(new Item(product));
    cartService.update(cart, sessionId);
}
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Incorrect request,     check request data")
public void handleClientErrors(Exception ex) { }
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason="Internal server error")
public void handleServerErrors(Exception ex) { }}
```

Cart model class:

```
public class Cart {

private String cartId;
private Map<String, Item> products = new HashMap<String, Item>();
private BigDecimal totalValue = new BigDecimal(0);

public Cart(String cartId) {
    this.cartId = cartId;
}


public String getCartId() {
    return cartId;
}

public void setCartId(String cartId) {
    this.cartId = cartId;
}

public Map<String, Item> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(Map<String, Item> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

public BigDecimal getTotalPrice() {
    return totalValue;
}

public void setTotalPrice(BigDecimal totalPrice) {
    this.totalValue = totalPrice;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CartDao{" +
            "cartId='" + cartId + '\'' +
            ", products=" + products +
            ", totalValue=" + totalValue +
            '}';
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Cart cart = (Cart) o;

    if (cartId != null ? !cartId.equals(cart.cartId) : cart.cartId != null) return false;
    if (products != null ? !products.equals(cart.products) : cart.products != null) return false;
    return totalValue != null ? totalValue.equals(cart.totalValue) : cart.totalValue == null;

}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = cartId != null ? cartId.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (products != null ? products.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (totalValue != null ? totalValue.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

public void addItemToCart(Item item) {
    String itemId = String.valueOf(item.getProduct().getId());

    if (products.containsKey(itemId)) {
        Item alreadyInCart = products.get(itemId);
        alreadyInCart.setQuantity(alreadyInCart.getQuantity() + item.getQuantity());
        products.put(itemId, alreadyInCart);
    } else {
        products.put(itemId, item);
    }
    updateTotalValue();
}

public void updateTotalValue() {
    totalValue = new BigDecimal(0);
    for (Item item : products.values()) {
        totalValue = totalValue.add(item.totalValue());
    }
}

public void removeItem(Item item){
    products.remove(item.getProduct().getId());
    updateTotalValue();

}

}
```

Item model class:

```
public class Item {


private Product product;
private Integer quantity;


public Item(){
    this.quantity = 1;
}

public Item(Product product){
    this.quantity = 1;
    this.product = product;
}

public Item(Product product, Integer quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.product = product;
}

public BigDecimal totalValue() {
    return this.product.getProductPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(this.quantity));
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Item{" +
            "product=" + product +
            ", quantity=" + quantity +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Item item = (Item) o;

    if (product != null ? !product.equals(item.product) : item.product != null) return false;
    return quantity != null ? quantity.equals(item.quantity) : item.quantity == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = product != null ? product.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (quantity != null ? quantity.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
}
```

Product model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Size(min = 4, max = 40, message = "{Size.Product.productName.validation}")
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
private String productName;

@Min(value = 0,    message = "{Min.Product.productPrice.validation}")
@Digits(integer = 8,fraction = 2,message = "{Digits.Product.productPrice.validation}")
@NotNull(message = "{NotNull.Product.productPrice.validation}")
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_PRICE")
private BigDecimal productPrice;

@NotBlank(message = "{NotBlank.Product.productDescription.validation}")
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION")
private String productDescription;

@NotNull(message = "NotNull.Product.category.validation")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Category category;

//    private MultipartFile productImage;

public Product() {
}

public Product(String productName, BigDecimal productPrice, String productDescription, Category category) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
    this.category = category;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public BigDecimal getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(BigDecimal productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Product product = (Product) o;

    if (id != product.id) return false;
    if (productName != null ? !productName.equals(product.productName) : product.productName != null) return false;
    if (productPrice != null ? !productPrice.equals(product.productPrice) : product.productPrice != null)
        return false;
    if (productDescription != null ? !productDescription.equals(product.productDescription) : product.productDescription != null)
        return false;
    return category != null ? category.equals(product.category) : product.category == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + (productName != null ? productName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (productPrice != null ? productPrice.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (productDescription != null ? productDescription.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (category != null ? category.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
            ", productPrice=" + productPrice +
            ", productDescription='" + productDescription + '\'' +
            ", category=" + category +
            '}';
}
}
```

Cart DAO:

```
@Repository("cartDao")
public class CartDaoImpl implements CartDao {


    private Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts;

    public CartDaoImpl() {
        listOfCarts = new HashMap<String, Cart>();
    }

    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        if(listOfCarts.containsKey(cart.getCartId()))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not create cart"
                    + "Cart with specified id (%) already exists.",cart.getCartId()));
        }
        listOfCarts.put(cart.getCartId(), cart);
        return cart;
    }

    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return listOfCarts.get(cartId);
    }


    public void update(Cart cart, String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.containsKey(cartId))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not update cart. "
                    + "Cart with specified id (%) does not exists.",cartId));
        }
        listOfCarts.put(cartId, cart);
    }

    public void delete(String cartId) {
        if(!listOfCarts.containsKey(cartId))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Can not update cart. "
                    + "Cart with specified id (%) does not exists.",cartId));
        }
        listOfCarts.remove(cartId);
    }
}
```

Controller.js

```
var cartApp = angular.module('cartApp', []);

cartApp.controller('cartCtrl',  function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.refreshCart = function(cartId) {

        $http.get('/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.cart = data;
            });
    };

    $scope.clearCart = function() {

        $http.delete('/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId)
            .success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));

    };

    $scope.initCartId = function(cartId) {

        $scope.cartId=cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function(productId) {
        $http.put('/rest/cart/add/'+productId)
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
                alert("Product has been succesfully added to cart!");
            });
    };
    $scope.removeFromCart = function(productId) {


        $http.put('/rest/cart/remove/'+productId)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
            });
    };
});
```

cart.jsp

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="<c:url value="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>

    <title>Cart</title>
</head>
<section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
    <div ng-controller="cartCtrl" ng-init="initCartId('${cartId}')" class="col-md-5">

        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-danger pull-left"
               ng-click="clearCart()"> <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Erase Cart
            </a> <a href="<spring:url value="/checkout?cartId=${cartId}"/>" class="btn btn-success pull-right"> <span
                class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> Confirm
        </a>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Unit price</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <%--<th>Total price</th>--%>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.products">
                <td>{{item.product.id}}-{{item.product.productName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.product.productPrice}}</td>
                <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                <%--<td>{{item.totalPrice}}</td>--%>
                <td><a href="#" class="label label-danger" ng-click="removeFromCart(item.product.id)">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></span> Delete
                </a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Total</th>
                <th>{{cart.totalValue}} PLN</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <a href="<spring:url value="/products" />" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon"></span> Continue shopping
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
</html>


<%--&lt;%&ndash;--%>
  <%--Created by IntelliJ IDEA.--%>
  <%--User: artur--%>
  <%--Date: 31.08.2016--%>
  <%--Time: 22:22--%>
  <%--To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.--%>
<%--&ndash;%&gt;--%>
<%--<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>--%>
<%--<html>--%>
<%--<head>--%>
    <%--<title>Cart</title>--%>
<%--</head>--%>
<%--<body>--%>

<%--<div class="container">--%>
    <%--<div class="row">--%>
        <%--<div class="col-xs-8">--%>
            <%--<div class="panel panel-info">--%>
                <%--<div class="panel-heading">--%>
                    <%--<div class="panel-title">--%>
                        <%--<div class="row">--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-6">--%>
                                <%--<h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Shopping Cart</h5>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-6">--%>
                                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">--%>
                                    <%--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Continue shopping--%>
                                <%--</button>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--</div>--%>
                <%--</div>--%>
                <%--<div class="panel-body">--%>
                    <%--<div class="row">--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x70">--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-4">--%>
                            <%--<h4 class="product-name"><strong>Product name</strong></h4><h4><small>Product description</small></h4>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-6">--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">--%>
                                <%--<h6><strong>25.00 <span class="text-muted">x</span></strong></h6>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-4">--%>
                                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="1">--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-2">--%>
                                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">--%>
                                    <%--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>--%>
                                <%--</button>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--<hr>--%>
                    <%--<div class="row">--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-2"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x70">--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-4">--%>
                            <%--<h4 class="product-name"><strong>Product name</strong></h4><h4><small>Product description</small></h4>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-6">--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">--%>
                                <%--<h6><strong>25.00 <span class="text-muted">x</span></strong></h6>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-4">--%>
                                <%--<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" value="1">--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-2">--%>
                                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">--%>
                                    <%--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"> </span>--%>
                                <%--</button>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--<hr>--%>
                    <%--<div class="row">--%>
                        <%--<div class="text-center">--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-9">--%>
                                <%--<h6 class="text-right">Added items?</h6>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                            <%--<div class="col-xs-3">--%>
                                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block">--%>
                                    <%--Update cart--%>
                                <%--</button>--%>
                            <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--</div>--%>
                <%--</div>--%>
                <%--<div class="panel-footer">--%>
                    <%--<div class="row text-center">--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-9">--%>
                            <%--<h4 class="text-right">Total <strong>$50.00</strong></h4>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                        <%--<div class="col-xs-3">--%>
                            <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block">--%>
                                <%--Checkout--%>
                            <%--</button>--%>
                        <%--</div>--%>
                    <%--</div>--%>
                <%--</div>--%>
            <%--</div>--%>
        <%--</div>--%>
    <%--</div>--%>
<%--</div>--%>


<%--</body>--%>
<%--</html>--%>
```

product.jsp

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css' />" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <%--<link href="<c:url value='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js' />" rel="script"/>--%>
    <%--<link href="<c:url value='/resources/js/controllers.js' />" rel="script"/>--%>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/controllers.js"/>"></script>
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/product.jpg"/>" alt="image"  style = "width:100%"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-5">
            <h3>${product.productName}</h3>
            <p>${product.productDescription}</p>
            <p>
                <strong>Product category: </strong><span class="label label-warning">${product.category.categoryName}</span>
            </p>


            <h4>$${product.productPrice} USD</h4>
            <p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large" ng-click="addToCart('${product.id}')">
                    <span class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> Order now
                </a>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/cart" />" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon-hand-right glyphicon"></span> Cart
                </a>
                <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                    <a href="<spring:url value="edit/${product.id}" />" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon-hand-right glyphicon"></span> Edit
                    </a>
                </sec:authorize>
                <a href="<spring:url value="/products" />" class="btn btn-default">
                    <span class="glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon"></span> Back
                </a>

            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</html>
```

Link to [git repository](https://github.com/ArturRog/Shop)

Comment: You are using `$http.put('/rest/cart/add/'+productId)` in the `addToCart` method, please using `$http.post` and try it.

Comment: It gives angular.min.js:96 POST http://localhost:8080/rest/cart/add/5 405 () and 'WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported Request method 'POST' not supported' in console. 
@LipingHuang

Comment: sorry, you already define it is `PUT`, please see my answer.

Comment: I've changed RequestMethod in CartRestController to POST. `addToCart` succeeded with `Product has been succesfully added to cart!`, but there is nothing in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to check your js codes ( I suppose you check whether the cart added on UI )

```
$scope.addToCart = function(productId) {
    $http.put('/rest/cart/add/'+productId)
        .success(function(data) {
            // here is the problem, you need to check what the $http.get return, supporse here should be the cartID as the parameter, or you need to update your refreshCart method which take the cart as the parameter
            $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
            alert("Product has been succesfully added to cart!");
        });
};
```

Comment: How can I check that? 
When I am trying to access it in `refreshCart` it gives me `[Object] object`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing cartId to the refreshCart function, you are passing a ***promise***

```
$http.get('/rest/cart/get/cartId') //this isn't what you think it is...
```

You already have cartId stored in your initCartId function:

```
   $scope.cartId=cartId;
```

**Use this instead:**

```
 $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);
```